# Swift 4 Decodable - Additional Variables

Tags: json, swift, struct, swift4, decodable

Something I havent figured out or have been able to find online as of yet.

Is there a way to add additional fields onto a struct containing the decodable protocol in which are not present in the JSON Data?

For example and simplicity, say I have an array of json objects structured as such

> {
>     "name": "name1",
>     "url": "www.google.com/randomImage"
>   }

but say I want to add a UIImage variable to that struct containing the decodable such as

```
struct Example1: Decodable {
    var name: String?
    var url: String?
    var urlImage: UIImage? //To add later
}
```

Is there a way to implement the decodable protocol in order to get the name and url from the JSON but allow me to add the UIImage later?

Comment: @Rob: I don't think so--since `UIImage` isn't `Decodable` it won't even synthesize the protocol conformance

Answer (score 24):

To exclude `urlImage` you must manually conform to `Decodable` instead of letting its requirements be synthesized:

```
struct Example1 : Decodable { //(types should be capitalized)
    var name: String?
    var url: URL? //try the `URL` type! it's codable and much better than `String` for storing URLs
    var urlImage: UIImage? //not decoded

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, url } //this is usually synthesized, but we have to define it ourselves to exclude `urlImage`
}
```

Before Swift 4.1 this only works if you add `= nil` to `urlImage`, even though the default value of `nil` is usually assumed for optional properties.

If you want to provide a value for `urlImage` at initialization, rather than using `= nil`, you can also manually define the initializer:

```
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        url = try container.decode(URL.self, forKey: .url)
        urlImage = //whatever you want!
    }
```

Comment: The compiler can actually synthesise `init(from:)` for you. You just need to say `var urlImage: UIImage? = nil` in order to satisfy its need for a default value for a property not listed in the `CodingKeys` (why it doesn't accept the implicit default value of `nil` I'm not too sure).

Comment: thanks so much! That is kinda weird and that was also my problem I suppose. I was assigning the nil value to my variable excluded from the json property and kept throwing errors.

Comment: Needing to explicitly assign `nil` is a bug in the behavior (oversight, really) which I'm fixing now. This should not be necessary in the future.

Comment: And this is now fixed in Swift 4.1, you can omit the `= nil` :)

Comment: Well in Swift 5 it requires the nil here. Also, it's nice to set it to nil as proposed in the comments but then how to you set it up after the decoding WITHOUT actually writting the init(from:) yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'd make urlImage a lazy var.  That way you don't have to worry about modifying the coding keys. All you have to do is write your getter, like so...

```
struct Example1 : Decodable {

    var name : String?
    var url  : URL?    // Better than String

    lazy var urlImage: UIImage? = {
        // Put your image-loading code here using 'url'
    }()
}
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is it only works for var. If I want to do something like `let example = ...`  I can't access urlImage anymore because example object is immutable now.

Comment: His example specifically said 'to add later' which is why I wrote it like that, but if you want it to be treated as a 'let', at least from the outside world, just use `private(set) lazy var lazyTest: Int = { ... }`