# Ignore non-Codable optional properties in Codable object

Tags: json, swift, swift4, codable, decodable

When conforming to `Codable` protocol, I cannot easily skip optional property of non-Codable class

In `Ride` struct we want to skip *encoding* and *decoding* of `driver` property, and just leave it `nil` when decoding:

```
  struct Ride: Codable {

    public var number: String
    public var passenger: Passenger? // Codable conforming
    public var driver: Driver?       // NSObject subclass, doesn't conform to Codable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case number
      case passenger
    }
  }
```

In this case I get a compile error

> Type 'Driver' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

So far the only solution I came with, is to encode and decode *manually* by providing following methods:

```
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    number = try? values.decode(String.self, forKey: .number)
    passenger = try? values.decode(Passenger.self, forKey: .passenger)
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(number, forKey: .number)
    try container.encode(passenger, forKey: .passenger)
}
```

Is there another way to skip an optional property? This would be much easier with bigger models.

Comment: This is a bug, see this comment chain: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104870/swift-4-decodable-additional-variables/46105080#comment79173417_46105080

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try providing a *default value* for `driver`. For instance, this compiled *without* errors on **Xcode 9.0**:

```
struct Ride: Codable {
    public var number: String
    public var passenger: Passenger? 
    public var driver: Driver? = nil

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case number
        case passenger
    }
}

struct Passenger: Codable { /* ... */ }

class Driver: NSObject { /* ... */ }
```

Quick test:

```
let rideJSON =
"""
{
    "number": "123"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let ride = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Ride.self, from: rideJSON)
print(ride) /* Ride(number: "123", passenger: nil, driver: nil) */
```

By the way, I used a `private CodingKeys` because that is what the compiler does by default as well ;)

Comment: The printed compiler error is strikingly helpful on this issue: `note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'driver' does not have a matching CodingKey and does not have a default value`

Comment: @mklbtz Good catch! Probably an improvement by **Xcode 9.2**... *or* we completely missed this (helpful!) message the first time around ;) Much people don't even bother to read/interpret such messages...