# Using CodingKeys enum in Swift 4.0 to ignore UIImage properties

Tags: ios, swift, codable

I have the following struct. The first 3 properties are decoded from JSON, and the 4th property is to use as a cache if the image is ever downloaded.

```
import UIKit

struct Thumbnail: Codable {
    let url: String
    let width: UInt
    let height: UInt

    var image: UIImage?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url
        case width
        case height
    }
}
```

When I try to compile Xcode tells me that Thumbnail doesn't conform to the Decodable protocol. I get that UIImage doesn't conform to Codable, but as I understand it using the CodingKeys enum should ignore `image` from the protocol? Any advise would be much appreciated :)

Comment: That's a bug that was fixed in Swift 4.1 – you can say `var image: UIImage? = nil` to work around it in prior versions. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/46104870/2976878

Comment: Perfect, thanks @Hamish. Stuck on Sierra here which explains it. Add your solution as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: I feel like this is close enough to the Q&A that I linked to above such that we can just close as a duplicate. The answer there notes that you needed to add `= nil` in order to make the code compile, and I've left a comment saying that you no longer need to do so in 4.1 and above. Thoughts?

Comment: @Hamish I would suggest adding your own answer (here or on the linked question), instead of relying on a comment to perpetuate the knowledge that Swift 4.1 changes the story. Comments are volatile.

Comment: For those curious, this was fixed in https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/11854

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4 Decodable - Additional Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104870/swift-4-decodable-additional-variables)

Comment: Personally I'd differentiate between this question and the other one, as the link one is asking *"How do I ignore a property in Codable conformance (irrespective of if it's type is Codable or not)?"* whereas this one is asking *"Why doesn't ignoring a property of non-conforming type conform to Codable?"*

I'm happy to mark as duplicate if that distinction isn't enough though.